# fatal: destination path '/var/cpanel/easy/apache/custom_opt_mods/Cpanel already exists and is not an empty directory

Tags: linux, git, apache, cpanel, mod-pagespeed

I am trying to to install https://github.com/pagespeed/cpanel

When i:

> git clone https://github.com/pagespeed/cpanel.git /var/cpanel/easy/apache/custom_opt_mods/Cpanel/

I receive the following error:

> fatal: destination path '/var/cpanel/easy/apache/custom_opt_mods/Cpanel already exists and is not an empty directory

Any idea on how to solve this issue and install the mod? any help please explain step by step as i am a novice trying to learn:

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Answer is here... There is a typo in $> cp -r Cpanel/* /var/cpanel/easy/apache/custom_opt_mods/Cpanel/ that should be $> cp -r cpanel/* /var/cpanel/easy/apache/custom_opt_mods/Cpanel/
https://github.com/pagespeed/cpanel/issues/13